# Incompatibility in AES java encryption and Node js decryption

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, encryption, aes

I am performing a encryption and decryption using AES algorithm in java and Node js, the code for them are :-

**Node Js:**

```js
//ENCRYPTION:

 var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
    var encryption_key = 'encryptionKey';

    // Convert JSON to string
    var data = JSON.stringify({
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Adam",
            "age" : 32
    });
    var encrypted_data = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, encryption_key).toString();

    // Here is the final data
    console.log(encrypted_data);

//DECRYPTION

var cipher_data = 'cipherDataToDecrypt';

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(cipher_data, encryption_key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(decrypted);
```

**Java Code:**

```
static String secret = "encryptionKey";

public static String encrypt(String plain) throws Exception {
        String result = null;


        byte[] saltData = RandomUtils.nextBytes(8);

        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        final byte[][] keyAndIV = GenerateKeyAndIV(32, 16, 1, saltData, secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), md5);
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyAndIV[0], "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(keyAndIV[1]);

        Cipher aesCBC = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        aesCBC.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        byte[] encrypted = aesCBC.doFinal(plain.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        byte[] random = RandomUtils.nextBytes(8);
        byte[] output = new byte[saltData.length+random.length+encrypted.length];
        int i = 0;
        for(byte b1 : random){
            output[i] = b1;
            i++;
        }
        for(byte b1 : saltData){
            output[i] = b1;
            i++;
        }
        for(byte b1 : encrypted){
            output[i] = b1;
            i++;
        }

        result = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(output);
        return result;
    }
    public static byte[][] GenerateKeyAndIV(int keyLength, int ivLength, int iterations, byte[] salt, byte[] password, MessageDigest md) {

        int digestLength = md.getDigestLength();
        int requiredLength = (keyLength + ivLength + digestLength - 1) / digestLength * digestLength;
        byte[] generatedData = new byte[requiredLength];
        int generatedLength = 0;

        try {
            md.reset();

            // Repeat process until sufficient data has been generated
            while (generatedLength < keyLength + ivLength) {

                // Digest data (last digest if available, password data, salt if available)
                if (generatedLength > 0)
                    md.update(generatedData, generatedLength - digestLength, digestLength);
                md.update(password);
                if (salt != null)
                    md.update(salt, 0, 8);
                md.digest(generatedData, generatedLength, digestLength);

                // additional rounds
                for (int i = 1; i < iterations; i++) {
                    md.update(generatedData, generatedLength, digestLength);
                    md.digest(generatedData, generatedLength, digestLength);
                }

                generatedLength += digestLength;
            }

            // Copy key and IV into separate byte arrays
            byte[][] result = new byte[2][];
            result[0] = Arrays.copyOfRange(generatedData, 0, keyLength);
            if (ivLength > 0)
                result[1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(generatedData, keyLength, keyLength + ivLength);

            return result;

        } catch (DigestException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        } finally {
            // Clean out temporary data
            Arrays.fill(generatedData, (byte)0);
        }
    }
    public static String decrypt(String cipherText) throws Exception {


        byte[] cipherData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText);
        byte[] saltData = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherData, 8, 16);


        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        final byte[][] keyAndIV = GenerateKeyAndIV(32, 16, 1, saltData, secret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), md5);
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyAndIV[0], "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(keyAndIV[1]);

        byte[] encrypted = Arrays.copyOfRange(cipherData, 16, cipherData.length);
        Cipher aesCBC = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        aesCBC.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        byte[] decryptedData = aesCBC.doFinal(encrypted);
        String decryptedText = new String(decryptedData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return decryptedText;
    }
```

The java code is compatible with encrypting and decrypting.
And the node js is also compatible with encrypting and decrypting.
Also if you encrypt in Node js, the java code is able to decrypt.
**But the problem arises when I encrypt in java and try to decrypt in Node Js** . It gives

**Node js output:**

```
throw new Error('Malformed UTF-8 data');
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong here or Is there any other way to do this kind of encryption and decryption in java ? Please suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: In the Java code, there is a url encoding/decoding, but not in the NodeJS code.

Comment: Yes, I have added it by mistake in java code. I have edited it, Still it Is not working

Comment: In the Java code use `byte[] random = "Salted__".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);` (and also better change the variable name). The OpenSSL format starts with the ASCII encoding of `Salted__` and not with a random byte sequence.

Comment: That really helped me. thanks @Topaco